# How can I make the ul contain li in its content box?

Tags: css, frontend

How can I make the following CSS into a more tidy and reasonable structure. If you examine the following code carefully. You can find the ul item is actually occupying a row ahead of, instead of containing, li items in a box. So what change can I make to have ul encapsulate all the four li items?

demo:    http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gghz8/

effect:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gghz8/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using floats on the li's, they are taken out of the flow of the document, meaning that the UL no longer knows the size of it's children, thus cannot expand it's size to suit it's children.

Put a float on the UL.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gghz8/2/

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/

When I develop my sites, I float pretty much everything. It just helps to keep things consistent and avoids issues like you have now.

Comment: Thanks! it's the pretties way to fix the issue. However will float take the item out of the normal flow of document? AFAIK only position:absolute will take them out of the normal flow of document

Comment: The float will take the UL out of the normal flow of the document, but if you float everything, everything knows where it is supposed to sit, how big it's children are, thus how big it needs to be. Don't forget to mark a correct answer, please. =)

Comment: according to http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/, "Floated elements remain a part of the flow of the web page. This is distinctly different than page elements that use absolute positioning. Absolutely positioned page elements are removed from the flow of the webpage". so what exactly changed its behaviour?

Comment: Here is an interesting article explaining about floats "Floats – In the float model, a box is first laid out according to the normal flow, then taken out of the flow and shifted to the left or right as far as possible. Content may flow along the side of a float." http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/understanding-css-floats/

Comment: Thanks that better explains the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Add clearfix css

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
   content: " "; /* 1 */
   display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
clear: both;
}

/**
* For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
*/

.cf {
   *zoom: 1;
}
```

Step 2 - Add class to html on UL

```
<ul class="cf">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gghz8/3/

Answer (score 0):

Put overflow: hidden; on that ul.

Comment: you don't want to do that if you have a dropdown menu

Comment: I agree, in that case I would use display:inline-block; on li items instead of float:left;

Comment: Bit dirty though when you have to cater for IE7 and hack your way through display:inline, when just using floats covers all bases. Especially in instances like this.